# Save form data in magento 2 custom table

Tags: magento2, database, adminhtml, forms, adminform

This is my Admint.phtml file. This form is in admin dashboard need to save the contents in new custom db.

```
<div class="testbox">

  <form action="/">
      <hr>
    <div class="accounttype">
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="cash" name="account" checked/>
      <label for="radioOne" class="radio">Cash</label>
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="percentage" class="radioper" name="account" />
      <label for="radioTwo" class="radio">Percentage</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Value" class="amttxt" required/></br>

      <label id="icon" for="days">No of days to enable cashback:</label>

      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Days" class="dayss" required/></br>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SUBMIT">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```